# Camunda form not appearing in User task

Tags: java, spring-boot, camunda, camunda-modeler

I have created a form and saved in resources directory of spring boot project.

I created a User Task and used the above mentioned form to load as part of the user task (as shown below).

[image]

Note that the form reference is the name of external form that was created in previous step.

but, when the I open the user task from task list, the form is not displayed.

Here is the form configuration (just a drop down and submit button) :
[image]

variable routes created properly (Map<String,String> type) in the service task before the user task.

```
    @Override
    public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {

        Map<String, String> routes = new HashMap<>();

        routes.put("001", "Route 1");
        routes.put("002", "Route 2");
        routes.put("003", "route 3");
         
         
        // delegateExecution.setVariable("routes", routes);

        ObjectValue batchesDataValue = Variables.objectValue(routes)
                .serializationDataFormat(Variables.SerializationDataFormats.JSON)
                .create();
        execution.setVariable("routes",batchesDataValue);

    }
```

Can someone tell me why the form is not getting displayed in the user task when opened from task list?
[image]

Comment: If you are using Camunda 7 - this link might help https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/user-guide/task-forms/#camunda-forms

Comment: Have you checked if the form is deployed - More/Deployments?